# Getting information from Facebook inside PhoneGap Build

Tags: javascript, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

Editted, per JesseMonroy650's request:

I've done a couple of hybrid apps before, though none commercially released.
I am using PhoneGap Build. Located here: https://build.phonegap.com/
I am not using any Desktop app.

Original content:

I am trying to get data from Facebook inside PhoneGap Build.

I've got a simple script that seems like it should work based on the [API](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/blob/master/README.md):

```
<script>
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

            function onDeviceReady() {

                var fbLoginSuccess = function(userData) {
                    alert("UserInfo: " + JSON.stringify(userData));
                    facebookConnectPlugin.getAccessToken(function(token) {
                        alert("Token: " + token);
                    }, function(err) {
                        alert("Could not get access token: " + err);
                    });
                }
                facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile"],
                        fbLoginSuccess,
                        function(error) {
                            alert("" + error)
                        }
                );
            }
</script>
```

And I believe I've setup my config.xml correctly:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect" version="0.9.0">
    <param name="APP_ID" value="<ACTUAL APP ID HERE>" />
    <param name="APP_NAME" value="<ACTUAL APP NAME HERE>" />
</gap:plugin>
```

But I don't get any alert about this (or console log, when I try that).

1. So my question is - am I correctly using the PhoneGap Build Facebook API here? What should I do differently?
2. This is a less important question - bonus points if someone can point out how I can get the same process working in the browser without installing Cordova locally - if that's even possible

Comment: Which version of `phonegap-version` are you using?

Comment: Your response has me wondering. So I must ask some questions. Please **answer the following in your post**. Is this your first hybrid App? Are you using the Desktop App? Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) ? Please do not assume the answer, please read the link. Once you have answer the question *in the post*, respond in the comments so I know you have added information to the post.

Comment: I want to use PhoneGap Build, as indicated in my title and in my question. If I can't use the Facebook API without installing the CLI, so be it, but the final product will be built using PhoneGap Build.

Comment: I'll ask one more time. Is this your first hybrid App? Are you using the Desktop App? Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001)? Please do not assume the answer, please read the link. Once you have answer the question in the post, respond in the comments so I know you have added information to the post.

Comment: The facebook plugin is one of the most troublesome plugins, second only to Google's GMC. The leading failure for this plugin is a misconception about how Phonegap works. The next is transcription errrors and incorrect versions. After that is improper application of the `whitelist` plugin and the associated `CSP`. And last, but not least, is a competing App on the same device; that is another app that uses facebook services (and likely the same plugin). -- As you might imagine giving you any sort of \*answer\*, would be of little value.

Comment: Besides checking the things I have already mentioned, I am going to recommend the following forums.
1. [Nitobi forum for Phonegap Build](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi)
2. [Google Group of Cordova/Phonegap](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/phonegap)
3. [Adobe Communities for Phonegap Build](https://forums.adobe.com/community/phonegap/build)
Best of Luck

Answer (score 2):

**For your first question:**

Add the below to your config.xml and ensure you place your config.xml in the root folder with your index.html file:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect">
    <param name="APP_ID" value="..." />
    <param name="APP_NAME" value="..." />
</gap:plugin>
```

Add the following to the  of your index.html file and every .html file that you want to access the plugin scripts:

```
<script scr="phonegap.js"></script>
<script src="cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js"></script > 
<script src="facebook-js-sdk.js"></script >
```

Now, read and follow the documentation located [here](https://github.com/phonegap-build/FacebookConnect/blob/df97806027da5ba54ab94e093c6b3c0f2ec5de5b/README.md). Be sure to pay attention to the paragraph titled "Facebook Requirements and Set-Up".

Once complete, upload your zipped project to [build.phonegap.com](https://build.phonegap.com) and wait for your project to be compiled.

**For your 2nd question:**

It's not possible to test it on browser by any means without installing Cordova. Currently it's "out of the box"

Answer (score 2):

I think you have some semicolons missing (like the one declaring fbLoginSuccess var), give it a try with this code

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {

    var fbLoginSuccess = function (userData) {
        alert("UserInfo: " + JSON.stringify(userData));
        facebookConnectPlugin.getAccessToken(function (token) {
            alert("Token: " + token);
        }, function (err) {
            alert("Could not get access token: " + err);
        });
    };
    facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile"],
            fbLoginSuccess,
            function (error) {
                alert("" + error);
            }
    );
}
</script>
```